# C# panorama view 2 titles

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

is it possible to give the panorama view with 2 pages, separate titles? for page 1 example "Heading 1" and page 2 "Heading 2", but not using the subheadings for each panorama item, but the title property of the main panorama control

thanx

Answer (score 1):

You could set the text of the title to nothing. Then use the Margin property of the subheadings to move them up to where the title would be.

When setting the margin put the second number as a negative to move the object up the page. (Example: Margin="0,-50,0,0")

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do this. This isn't with the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202912%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

But maybe you can try it without a `Title`. just using the `Subheadings` and `Pivot` Controls in the panorama item content. But I think there is no guideline for doing this^^